# pointerdown does not work with radio button elements?

Tags: html

I have a radio button, but it seems pointerdown doesn't trigger when clicking on the element. I've tried inline and using an event handler, but neither work. As well, I can use pointerdown on a button just fine, it's only the radio button that seems to have an issue.

```html
<!--does not work-->
<input id="tabs-0" type="radio" name="tabs" onpointerdown="tabClick()" class="no-display" checked>
    <label for="tabs-0" class="default-text radio-label button button-choice">test</label>
<!--also does not work-->
<input id="tabs-1" type="radio" name="tabs" onpointerdown="tabClick()" class="no-display">
    <label for="tabs-1" class="default-text radio-label button">test</label>    
<!-- does work-->
<button data-choice class="clear default-text button" onpointerdown="tabClick()">+</button>
```

Comment: Quite unclear what your exact case here. Should we assume, by the class-name that the actual <input> elements are hidden and that you click on the nearby <label>?

Comment: While that wasn't the idea originally, it seems like `onclick` will pass through to a radio button, even if the radio button has the `display: none;` CSS property applied. However, pointer events are _not_ captured. I found a work around though.

Answer (score 0):

I works fine for me check this

```js
function tabClick(){
            console.log('abc ')
        }
```

```html
<body>
    <input id="tabs-0" type="radio" name="tabs" onpointerdown="tabClick()" class="no-display" checked>
    <label for="tabs-0" class="default-text radio-label button button-choice">test</label>
    <!--also does not work-->
    <input id="tabs-1" type="radio" name="tabs" onpointerdown="tabClick()" class="no-display">
    <label for="tabs-1" class="default-text radio-label button">test</label>
    <!-- does work-->
    <button data-choice class="clear default-text button" onpointerdown="tabClick()">+</button>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

@Kaiido pointed me in the right direction, so I'm posting the answer here for posterity.

It appears `onclick` will pass through to a radio button, even if the radio button has the `display: none;` CSS property applied. However, pointer events are *not* captured. As a work around, I simple moved the `onpointerdown` event handler to the label, rather than the input itself.